# What's the purpose of adding water to an egg wash?

Tags: baking, eggs, water

Many recipes I've seen call for beating a tablespoon or so of water in with the egg for an egg wash.

What is the effect of adding the water to the egg wash when baking?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proteins in a fresh egg are too viscous, even when thoroughly beaten, to wash a baked good.

The water thins the proteins so you get a nice glaze instead of a layer of scrambled egg.

Older eggs have sometimes degraded enough that they don't need the water but it is easier to always add water than to make a subjective judgement on the state of your egg proteins.